# headerShown, headerTitle and other options not working on Screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm new on React Native and I'm trying to create some things just for learning and testing...

Now, I'm trying to create an app with a login screen and some other screens in "logged area". So, I want to use the Header bar on "logged area" screens, but not on the Login screen.

For this, I'm trying to use React-Navigation, with options on `Stack.Screen`. But isn't working...

Here's my current code:

```
[...]
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
[...]
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator headerMode="screen">
    <Stack.Screen headerTitle="Test" headerShown={false} screenOptions={{headerTitle: 'Test', headerShown: false}} name="Login" component={Login} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
[...]
```

I'm testing if `headerTitle` and `headerShown` works as property or as `screenOptions`' option... But nothing is working.

Now, my screen has a "Login" title in header (ignoring the `headerTitle` property and option) and is showing the header (ignoring the `headerShown` property and option).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[screenOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#screenoptions) is a prop from Stack.Navigator, not from Stack.Screen.

[headerTitle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#headertitle) and [headerShown](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#headershown) are both options and not props, thus they must be inside options.

So either change 'screenOptions' to just 'options':

```
<Stack.Screen options={{headerTitle: 'Test', headerShown: true}} name="Login" component={Login} />
```

Or move this to Stack.Navigator (beware, it would be applied to all screens inside your navigator):

```
<Stack.Navigator headerMode="screen" screenOptions={{headerTitle: 'Test', headerShown: true}}>
```

Comment: Holy sh** man!! Veery thanks :D I've been trying to do this for 3 days and your solution helped me a lot!!! Very very very thanks rsrs